# Secure a GraphQL API with passport + JWT's or sessions? (with example)

Tags: node.js, authentication, session, graphql, jwt

To give a bit of context: I am writing an API to serve a internal CMS in React that requires Google login and a React Native app that should support SMS, email and Apple login, I am stuck on what way of authentication would be the best, I currently have an example auth flow below where a team member signs in using Google, a refresh token gets sent in a httpOnly cookie and is stored in a variable in the client, then the token can be exchanged for an accessToken, the refresh token in the cookie also has a tokenVersion which is checked before sending an accessToken which does add some extra load to the database but can be incremented if somebody got their account stolen, before any GraphQL queries / mutations are allowed, the user's token is decoded and added to the GraphQL context so I can check the roles using graphql-shield and access the user for db operations in my queries / mutations if needed

Because I am still hitting the database even if it's only one once on page / app load I wonder if this is a good approach or if I would be better off using sessions instead

```
// index.ts
import "./passport"

const main = () => {
  const server = fastify({ logger })
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: applyMiddleware(schema, permissions),
    context: (request: Omit<Context, "prisma">) => ({ ...request, prisma }),
    tracing: __DEV__,
  })

  server.register(fastifyCookie)
  server.register(apolloServer.createHandler())
  server.register(fastifyPassport.initialize())

  server.get(
    "/auth/google",
    {
      preValidation: fastifyPassport.authenticate("google", {
        scope: ["profile", "email"],
        session: false,
      }),
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
    async () => {}
  )

  server.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    {
      preValidation: fastifyPassport.authorize("google", { session: false }),
    },
    async (request, reply) => {
      // Store user in database
      // const user = existingOrCreatedUser
      // sendRefreshToken(user, reply) < send httpOnly cookie to client
      // const accessToken = createAccessToken(user)
      // reply.send({ accessToken, user }) < send accessToken
    }
  )
      
  server.get("/refresh_token", async (request, reply) => {
    const token = request.cookies.fid

    if (!token) {
      return reply.send({ accessToken: "" })
    }

    let payload

    try {
      payload = verify(token, secret)
    } catch {
      return reply.send({ accessToken: "" })
    }

    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id: payload.userId },
    })

    if (!user) {
      return reply.send({ accessToken: "" })
    }

    // Check live tokenVersion against user's one in case it was incremented
    if (user.tokenVersion !== payload.tokenVersion) {
      return reply.send({ accessToken: "" })
    }

    sendRefreshToken(user, reply)

    return reply.send({ accessToken: createAccessToken(user) })
  })

  server.listen(port)
}
```

```
// passport.ts
import fastifyPassport from "fastify-passport"
import { OAuth2Strategy } from "passport-google-oauth"

fastifyPassport.registerUserSerializer(async (user) => user)
fastifyPassport.registerUserDeserializer(async (user) => user)

fastifyPassport.use(
  new OAuth2Strategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback",
    },
    (_accessToken, _refreshToken, profile, done) => done(undefined, profile)
  )
)
```

```
// permissions/index.ts
import { shield } from "graphql-shield"
import { rules } from "./rules"

export const permissions = shield({
  Mutation: {
    createOneShopLocation: rules.isAuthenticatedUser,
  },
})
```

```
// permissions/rules.ts
import { rule } from "graphql-shield"
import { Context } from "../context"

export const rules = {
  isAuthenticatedUser: rule()(async (_parent, _args, ctx: Context) => {
    const authorization = ctx.request.headers.authorization

    if (!authorization) {
      return false
    }

    try {
      const token = authorization.replace("Bearer", "")
      const payload = verify(token, secret)

      // mutative
      ctx.payload = payload

      return true
    } catch {
      return false
    }
  }),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you want to be using jwts for access and that's it. These jwts should be created tied to a user session, but you don't want to have to manage them. You want a user identity aggregator to do it.

You are better off removing most of the code to handle user login/refresh and use a user identity aggregator. You are running into common problems of the complexity when handling the user auth flow which is why these exist.

The most common is Auth0, but the price and complexity may not match your expectations. I would suggest going through the list and picking the one that best supports your use cases:

- [Auth0](https://auth0.com)
- [Okta](https://okta.com)
- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)
- [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/)
- [Authress](https://authress.io)

Or you can check out [this article](https://authress.io/knowledge-base/how-to-pick-best-auth-solution) which suggests a bunch of different alternatives as well as what they focus on